# Determine cipher being used in https connection

Tags: javascript, php, apache, ssl, https

Using php (under Apache) or JavaScript is there any way to determine the Cipher Suite or Cipher Spec being used for the current SSL (https) connection (i.e. rsa_aes_256_sha)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server side, in PHP, you should be able to access [`mod_ssl`'s `SSL_CIPHER` environment variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) using PHP's [`$_SERVER` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). You'll also need to use `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars` in your Apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I checked the $_SERVER global with a var_dump and can find no reference to SSL_CIPHER. Nor does it seem to be a global (var_dump($GLOBAL)) in my test PHP page. The only SSL related global seems to be HTTPS which is a string boolean.  I use goDaddy as a host is there a way I can check if SSLOptions and StdEnvVars is enabled from PHP?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I suspect not. I'd suggest contacting your hosting service to ask them.

Comment: I dug deeper Bruno and found I can enable SSLOptions +StdEnvVars in the .htaccess file.  Once this option was in place the the SSL environment variables appeared including $_SERVER["SSL_CIPHER"]   Thanks.